# splitting a string in VB

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a ComboBox which I assign to a variable:

```
Dim var as String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue 
Dim name As String = var.Split(",")
```

This gives me the error

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of string' cannot be converted to String

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Lance, VB6 doesn't support the initializers that are shown.

Comment: @agent, thanks, I work mostly with VBA and wasn't sure if VB6 did or not.

Comment: Its the latest version of VB, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split returns an **array** of strings.  Your variable needs to be changed to an array, not just a single string.

Answer (score 1):

name needs to be declared as an array.

```
dim name() as string = var.split(",")
```

The split() method will break up the string based on the given character and put each newly created string into an array and return it.

This is what your error message is telling you:

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of string' cannot be converted to String
```

The method returns an array of string, but your trying to put it into just a string!

**EDIT:** In response to your answer...

So far you've managed to split the string yourself with the split method.  To output this to your message box, you need to concatenate the two elements in the proper order:

```
msgbox(name(1) & " " & name(0))
```

Notice I indexed the array twice!  Element 1 is the first name, element 0 is the last name.  Remember you got this name in lname,fname format. Passing the array itself doesn't make sense!  Remember, a datatype is not equal to an array of that type, they are two different things.  Therefore a string is not compatible with a string array.  However, each individual element of the array is a string, and so each of those are compatible with the string type (because they're the same thing)!

Comment: When I add Name to an array value I am now getting the error. "Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid." This is at runtime on the line "Dim var As String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue" –

Comment: @user765942 Convert the SelectedValue to a string by calling it's .ToString() method.

Comment: I've used to ToString() method, however im now getting this error when I run... "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'." This is when I try and display the result in a message box - MsgBox(name)

Comment: @user765942 That's occuring because you're passing the array to MsgBox.  MsgBox expects a string.  What exactly are you trying to do?  I can write an answer to help you better if you explain your problem a bit.

Comment: Basically I have a ComboBox which displays a list of names. This list of names is formatted with 'Surname, FirstName'. I want to split the string on the ',' and change its order so it is displayed as 'FirstName Surname'. Hope I've explained that properly!

Comment: Im using the MessageBox just to validate]

Comment: @user765942 See Edits in answer.

Answer (score 1):

My VB is a bit rusty, but I think you have to make `name` an array:

```
Dim name() As String = var.Split(",")
```

Comment: When I add Name to an array value I am now getting the error. "Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid." This is at runtime on the line "Dim var As String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue"

Comment: Replace `Dim var as String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue` with `Dim var as String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim var As String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
 Dim temp() As String = Split(var, ",", -1, CompareMethod.Binary)
 Dim name As String = temp(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe "name" isn't an array and the goal is to populate "name" with everything up until the first comma, in which case the fix would be:

```
Dim name as String = var.Split(",")(0)
```

Note: assumes that var is not Nothing.